# Pymongo - Mod on _id not allowed

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a Mongo Collection that I need to update, and I'm trying to use the collection.update command to no avail.

Code below:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.SensorDB
sensors = db.Sensor

for sensor in sensors.find():
    lat = sensor['location']['latitude']
    lng = sensor['location']['longitude']
    sensor['location'] = {
        "type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [lat ,lng]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": sensor['name']
        }
    }

    sensors.update({'webid': sensor['webid']} , {"$set": sensor}, upsert=True)
```

However, running this gets me the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "purgeDB.py", line 21, in <module>
    cameras.update({'webid': sensor['webid']} , {"$set": sensor}, upsert=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 561, in update
    check_keys, self.uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1118, in _send_message
    rv = self.__check_response_to_last_error(response, command)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1060, in __check_response_to_last_error
    raise OperationFailure(details["err"], code, result)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Mod on _id not allowed
```

Comment: You cannot update the "_id" of an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
for sensor in sensors.find():
```

to this:

```
for sensor in sensors.find({}, {'_id': 0}):
```

What this does is prevent Mongo from returning the `_id` field, since you aren't using it, and it's causing your problem later in your `update()` call since you cannot "update" `_id`.

---

An even better solution (Only write the data that is needed)

```
for sensor in sensors.find():
    lat = sensor['location']['latitude']
    lng = sensor['location']['longitude']
    location = {
        "type" : "Feature",
        "geometry" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [lat ,lng]
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": sensor['name']
        }
    }

    sensors.update({'webid': sensor['webid']} , {"$set": {'location': location}})
```

**Edit:**
As mentioned by Loïc Faure-Lacroix, you also do not need the `upsert` flag in your case - your code in this case is always updating, and never inserting.

**Edit2:** 
Surrounded `_id` in quotes for first solution.

Comment: also the upsert flag is not needed. It should be removed as there shouldn't be new documents created.

Comment: Also, ```new_doc = copy.deepcopy(mongo_doc)``` produces a cloned dict you can edit and upsert with ```{"$set": new_doc}``` after you ```del new_doc['_id']``` if your documents are super big and lots changes when you edit them (e.g. a big user profile)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Update the projection to not return `_id` solved the issue for me.